# Remove next character jQuery (no html elements given)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

Suppose the following markup:

```
    <body>
      <a href=# name="uniqueLink1">link</a> [ some text here
      <a href=# name="uniqueLink2">link</a> [ some more text here
    </body>
```

Is there anyway to use jQuery to remove the ' [ ' from the top line but not the bottom one?

Note: I don't have the access to the markup, but I can add elements, `divs` etc. using jQuery if I wanted to. BUT jQuery does not need to target the `string` of ' ] ' in particular - it can be something like "remove next 3 characters after `uniqueLink1`.

Comment: That `[ some text here` is not wrapped by any html element except `body`?

Comment: You should wrap the text with some element `p`, `div`, `span`...

Comment: @HieuNguyen correct - no html elements around the text, I've added more details - it can be as simple as 'remove next character' or something like that.

Comment: Does not work. See @Fabricio's answer

Comment: @Alvaro I agree but I don't have access to the markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery doesn't really help much with manipulating text nodes, but here it is:

```
var tn = $('a[name="uniqueLink1"]')[0].nextSibling;
tn.nodeValue = tn.nodeValue.replace('[', '');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FQz9G/)

---

`$()[n]` is a shorthand for [`$().get(n)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/), so `[0]` will return a reference to the first matched DOM element inside the jQuery object, the `uniqueLink1` anchor.

[`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling), as the name implies, grabs the next sibling node. In this case, the text node that follows the given anchor element.

[`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue) gets and sets the content of the text node.

[`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) given a string as the first argument replaces only the first occurrence, thus this should be enough enough given the DOM structure is similar to the posted one.

Comment: I can't believe it it's exactly what I needed! thanks!!

Comment: Nice :) It works. In my case i wanted to remove parenthesis around the element so i used "previousSibling" too

Answer (score 0):

This will filter the textnodes, and remove a `[` from the first on it finds:

```
var textNode = $('body').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).eq(1);
textNode.replaceWith(document.createTextNode(textNode[0].textContent.replace('[','')));
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/euvHk/)